# Mi formulario de windows forms no realiza el cálculo como lo esperaba

Tags: c#, windows-forms

[image: Imagen del formulario]

Hola! Me encuentro con un problema al hacer una ejercitación de windows forms. Diseño un formulario, en el que tengo 4 checkbox que, al cambiar a checked=true, habilitan sus respectivas textBox para ingresar únicamente valores numéricos. Mi inconveniente radica en que, de la forma que tengo el código, si no tengo los cuatro checks tildados (siendo ejecutado), se detiene, indicándome que los valores que habilitan los checkBox no tildados no se encuentran (System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.'). Intente inicializar los valores numéricos de los textBox en 0, pero al hacerlo, el cálculo me devuelve siempre cero.
De más está decir que soy nuevo en este lenguaje y es mi primer post en esta web, por lo que, si algo no está claro o infrinjo alguna norma, les pido disculpas.
Agradecería su ayuda en el caso y también que se hayan tomado la molestia de leerlo.
Saludos.

Esto sería el código que puse en el evento click del botón "Calcular"

```
`public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Declaración de variables
        //double orden1 = 0;
        double orden2 = 0;
        double orden3 = 0;
        double orden4 = 0;
        

        private void btnCalcular_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Cantidad de órdenes 
            double orden1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtBoxCombo1.Text);
            double orden2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtBoxCombo2.Text);
            double orden3 = Convert.ToDouble(txtBoxCombo3.Text);
            double orden4 = Convert.ToDouble(txtBoxCombo4.Text);

            //Precios
            double precio1 = 100;
            double precio2 = 260;
            double precio3 = 300;
            double precio4 = 375;

            //Cálculos
            double final1 = orden1 * precio1;
            double final2 = orden2 * precio2;
            double final3 = orden3 * precio3;
            double final4 = orden4 * precio4;
            double subtotal = final1 + final2 + final3 + final4;
            double iva = subtotal * 0.21;
            double total = subtotal + iva;

            //Mostrar
            txtBoxSubtotal.Text = Convert.ToString(subtotal);
            txtBoxIva.Text = Convert.ToString(iva);
            txtBoxTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
           
        }`
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! me explicas esta frase "si no tengo los cuatro checks tildados, no me compila"... o sea, el tiempo de compilacion no tiene nada que ver con el tiempo de ejecucion.. ylos checks se marcan en tiempo de ejecucion... podrias ser mas claro con el problema? el problema son los textbox vacios? (sigue)

Comment: si el problema viene por ahi, no uses convert.Toxxxx, en su caso, usa [Double.TryParse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-6.0) ... y para valores de montos usa decimal (ya vas a ver mas adelante problemas de redondeos con double)

Comment: Para ser exactos, no puedes siquiera abrir el programa o sí puedes pero surge un error (excepción)?

Comment: Perdón, me expresé mal. Tal cual está el código, me lo ejecuta. Mientras está siendo ejecutado, puedo hacer el cálculo como lo tenía previsto si tildo los checks de los cuatros "combos". Pero, si no llegara a tildar uno, el cálculo no se hace y me detiene la ejecución, arrojando el siguiente mensaje: System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.'   En la "orden" que corresponde al check que no está tildado. No sé si estoy siendo lo suficientemente claro (o si lo empeoré :D)

Comment: en la pregunta, va el error completo, y la linea donde sale.. dejamos de ser magos hace muchisimo tiempo :P... igual, ya te señale tu problema, en mi segundo comentario....

Comment: Aprecio el sarcasmo y que te hayas tomado el tiempo de responder. Lo intentaré. Gracias.